# Eclipse cannot find R.layout.simple_list_item_1

Tags: android, eclipse-adt

I am building my first Android project using Eclipse ADT.

I tried populating a LIstView, and to that end I created a ArrayAdaptor.

Now, I can not find `R.layout.simple_list_item_1`, which is supposed to be android supplied?  I have 'Android 4.3' libraries included in my project and I can see 'simple_list_item_1.xml' in android.jar/res/layout.

Any pointers to what could be missing here?

Comment: Did you use `android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1`?

Comment: If the above does not work, try cleaning your project.

Comment: Are you using the full name of the layout? `android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1` - `R.layout.simple_list_item_1` probably won't be enough if you have your own R file imported in the class.

Comment: Welcome, glad we could help!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Remember that most times you are using the R class generated for your own project, and if you have used some R attribute in your code before and use auto import, the "R" in your code will then reference your project's R class.

Instead use android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1 to specifically reference Android's R class and you should be fine.